# Emacs backups - why backup all files to a single directory?

Tags: backup

I was updating my emacs backup approach using ideas from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files), but I'm left unsure by one aspect, namely: the fact that several of them arrange to have backups placed in a single backup directory. So they might have something like:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs.d/backups")))
```

That's in contrast to what I've been doing up until now, with each "actual" directory having it's own backup directory, using something like:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "backups")))
```

That has seemed sensible to me since it keeps any given file's backups close to it in the filesystem. As a result, if and when I need a copy of a backup, I just drop into `./backups` instead of having to climb out of whatever Mines of Moria-esque subdir I've been working in, drag my sorry a*se all the way over to `~/.emacs.d/backups` or the like, and then dive into a haystack of mostly unrelated files with blindingly !-infested full pathnames, to find the needle that is my desired backup. Not to mention the fact that backing up to a single directory creates a risk that sensitive files may get backed up to a place with less than sensitive permissions.

Nevertheless, reading around the topic I now get the impression that the single directory approach may in fact be the norm, and that *I'm* the weirdo.

**So what am I missing?**
Is there some gotcha to the per-directory approach? Or some really useful benefit with the single directory approach? Or both? Or what?

Comment: The question is too broad, and encourages opinion-based answers. It should be closed, IMO. Consider raising such an open question on a discussion sites such as Reddit, instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is no accounting for taste.

Comment: I'm really hoping that's not all there is to it, but I won't be surprised if you're right. +1 anyway.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20809)

Comment: @NickD, you're probably right, from an SE point of view anyway (which, yes, is what matters here). That said, as the question's author I do take some value from db48x's quip.  It really is possible that there is little or no significance in the choice I'm asking about, in which case, just as with a question like _"Why, after pouring their milk into their tea, do some people stir clockwise, and some anti-clockwise?"_, a good, if not the best answer may well be what is tantamount to a verbal shrug. 

Comment: I stand by my answer that it is purely a matter of taste, but you’re welcome to answer as well if you can think of a better one.

Comment: What @NickD said. (I raised the same flag.)